# Function to register button click handlers on JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I have a PHP variable call $id, which can be 1 or 2, and I have two buttons with ids #readmore1 and #readmore2. The code below to register the click handlers is working perfectly, but I wanted to refactor it.

Is there a way to do it passing somehow the PHP variable to JS?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#readmore1").click(function() {
        if ($("#readmore1").text() == "Show More") {
            $("#readmore1").text("Show Less");
        }
        else {
            $("#readmore1").text("Show More");
        }
    });
    $("#readmore2").click(function() {
        if ($("#readmore2").text() == "Show More") {
            $("#readmore2").text("Show Less");
        }
        else {
            $("#readmore2").text("Show More");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This question does not fully explain what you want. Where do you want these php variables? How does your PHP interact with the JS? PHP is rendered server-side before it reaches the client, where javascript is executed, so you need to better explain what you are thinking in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it passing somehow the PHP variable to JS?

Not in sense of "passing a value to a function". But you can use PHP to *generate* the JS and inject values from PHP in the process.

However, that might not actually be the best solution. Why don't you just give both elements the same class?

```
$(".readmore").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Show More") {
        $(this).text("Show Less");
    }
    else {
        $(this).text("Show More");
    }
});
```

jQuery will bind this handler to all elements with class `readmore`.